# Using text as background

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using this code to add an image background to my file:

```
<fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute"
                        top="-1cm" left="-3cm" width="26cm" height="29.7cm"
                        background-image="Pictures/afbeelding.png">
                        <fo:block/>
</fo:block-container>
```

This code works fine. I now want to try someting new.

**Is it also possible to add a String as background?**
**Can I also determine the position of the string?**
I want this string to be positioned diagonally from the top left corner to the bottom right one.

I have searched for a solution but dindn`t find one.

Comment: If you use apache fop, I think you can use an svg image as backgroud where you could easily store a "String"

Comment: @StefanHegny Thx, don`t know if it`s possible but i will take a look at it !

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012480/setting-xsl-fo-background-image-from-embedded-svg for using an svg as a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use text as a background. To make sure the background text is rendered as a background, and not on top of the body text:

- place the text in one of the `static-content` frames
- use a `block-container` with `absolute-position` to place the container underneath the body frame

```html
<fo:static-content flow-name="inside">
   <fo:block-container width="170mm" absolute-position="absolute" top="100mm" left="20mm">
        <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="45pt" font-weight="bold"  axf:transform="rotate(-45deg)">
       <xsl:text>Watermark text</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
   </fo:block-container>
</fo:static-content>
```

- in your `fo:simple-page-master`, the order of the regions determines which content is rendered on top. The regions are processed in order, later regions will be drawn on top of earlier ones. Put the `region-body` last in the list, and it will be drawn on top of all others:

```html
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="odd">   
     <fo:region-before/>
     <fo:region-after/>
     <fo:region-start/>
     <fo:region-end/>
     <fo:region-body/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
```

If you use Antennahouse, you can rotate the fo:block to a diagonal orientation: `axf:transform="rotate(-45deg)"`

The advantage of using this approach compared to putting the text in an SVG element: in an SVG, the text cannot span more than one line. Each line has to become a separate SVG element, and you have to split the text manually. Using my method the text ends up in an fo:block which does support line breaks, hyphenation etc.

Comment: Htx i Will try this solution also, I have also used SVG this works fine!

Comment: I am testing your solution so That i can vote for your answer but didn`t succeed yet. Can you give an example code? and I am not using Antennahouse

Comment: it work but transform doesn`t work and I can not add opacity or font color ?

Comment: you can add a font color to the fo:block (color="#6C6F70"), because the text is in the background opacity can be 100% without causing problems.

Comment: Works fine i have voted for you answer dont know yet if it is possible to rotate